# Expression to look up certain character and store it in SSIS variable

Tags: t-sql, variables, ssis, expression

In SSIS 2008 I have a variable called `@[User::EANcode]` It contains a string with a product eancode like `'1234567891123'`. The value is derived from a filename like`'1234567891123.jpg'` via a foreach loop.

However, sometimes the filenames contain an extra '_1', '_2' etc. at the end like '1234567891123_1.jpg' resulting in a value '1234567891123_1' in the EANcode variable.

This happens when there is more than one image for the same EANcode (product). The _N addition is always a number and it is always at the end of the name/string.

**What is the expression to find/cath the '_1' (or_2 or_N etc) so you can store it in another variable called `@[User::Addition]`?**

If there is no addition, the variable stays empty which is fine.

The reason I need to get this _N addition into a separate variable is that I later on need it to rename the filename but paste the addition back at the end.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for `CHARINDEX()` in conjunction with `SUBSTRING()`.  With that, you can split off that _# to another variable like this  (copy/pasta and execute to see.  Play with the @temp1 variable to see the limitations of the code):

```
declare @temp1 varchar(20), @temp2 varchar(20)
set @temp1 = '1234567891123_12'

IF CHARINDEX('_', @temp1) > 1
set @temp2 = SUBSTRING(@temp1,CHARINDEX('_', @temp1),LEN(@temp1)-CHARINDEX('_',@temp1)+1)

select @temp1, @temp2
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks, the substring brought me to an idea to use it in the separate variable. The code for the addition part is actually simple: SUBSTRING( @[User::EANcode] ,14,3)

Comment: @J3FFK - Nice!  I wasn't sure if it was variable length numbers before or after the `_`, so I accounted for that in my answer. :)  Substring(@user,14,3) is definitely easier if the length doesn't vary!